# Can not filter RxJS Observable on Angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs

Here's a snippet that fetches data from a REST service:

```
getPlayers(position: string) {
    return this.get(`players/${position}`)
        .map(r => r.data)
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
            return Observable.of<Player>();
        });
}
```

**r.data** is an array of players.

This is how I define the variable that will hold the reference to what the service above returns:

```
  players: Observable<Player>;
```

Finally this is how I assign the players:

```
this.players = this.svc.getPlayers(this.position);
```

This is how I list the players on the component:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let player of players | async">
  {{player.name}}-{{player.position}}
</ion-item>
```

Everything works as expected. Now I want to filter the players before showing them on the component and I try something like this;

```
this.players = this.svc.getPlayers(this.position).filter(p => p.position === 'hq');
```

...and I see nothing on screen as if I don't have any records to show. None of the observable methods seem to work correctly.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Could you please confirm if the filtered data have any elements in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following to apply filter :

Change your service as below :

```
getPlayers(position: string) {
    return this.get(`players/${position}`)
        .map(r => r.json())
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
            return [];
        });
}
```

//In your component :

```
players: Player[];

//Call your service to get data and remove async pipe from HTML
this.svc.getPlayers(this.position).subscribe(res => {
  this.players = (res.data.length) ? res.data.filter(p => p.position === 'hq'):[];
});
```

Comment: The `players` is an Observable object. So we need to change it to `array`  and also to remove `async` pipe from view

Comment: It seems that by using Subscribe alone, the service is never get to called. Also by removing the "async" pipe from the template, I get "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Comment: change `r => r.data` to `r => r.json().data` and check if object error is resolved or not

Comment: @ranakrunal9 My bad, your answer works as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
.map(r => r.data.filter(p => p.position === 'hq'))

this.players = this.svc.getPlayers(this.position);
```